# Datatables rowReorder can't move row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I wish I could be more descriptive, but that simply is what's happening: you can't move the rows.

I know datatables is loading in correctly and I know that the responsive plugin works as well. I just added this and updated datatables to 1.10.25 in case that was relevant

Here is my code:

.js:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/select2-4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/DataTables-1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/RowReorder-1.2.8/js/rowReorder.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/Responsive-2.2.7/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#identifier').DataTable({
        rowReorder: true,
        responsive: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false
    });
});
```

.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/datatables/DataTables-1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/datatables/RowReorder-1.2.8/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/datatables/Responsive-2.2.7/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
```

and .html:

```
    <table id="identifier" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 1</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 2</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 3</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 4</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 5</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 6</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="centered-content">1</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td class="centered-content"><button>Do Something</button></td>
            </tr>
            ...
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 1</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 2</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 3</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 4</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 5</th>
                <th class="centered-content">Row 6</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel stupid, but I figured out my problem:

you have to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/RowReorder-1.2.8/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
```

not

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/RowReorder-1.2.8/js/rowReorder.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

They both are in the library folder, but are not equivalent. Guess its just one of those days.

Comment: Glad you resolved it. [This page](https://datatables.net/download/index) is useful for helping to ensure your resources are correct.